# Vapor 4: Children relation not eager loaded, use $ prefix to acces

Tags: swift, backend, vapor, vapor-fluent

Currently I am working on a school assignment where we have to build an API using Vapor. I have a few basic API calls working and I am trying a bit more advanced API calls now but I can't get this to work.

I have this function `addToParty` that is being called when the URL `/party/join/:partyID` is called with a body

```
{
    "id": "CC1FAC6B-A2B3-471C-A488-147300196981",
    "username": "string",
    "is_ready": true
}
```

I am trying to find a party by the partyId and add the user to the list of users of the party.

```
func addToParty (req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Party.Output> {
    guard let id = req.parameters.get("partyID", as: UUID.self) else {
        throw Abort(.badRequest)
    }
    let input = try req.content.decode(Party.JoinParty.self)
    return Party.find(id, on: req.db)
        .unwrap(or: Abort(.notFound))
        .flatMap { element in
        element.users.append(User(id: UUID(input.id), username: input.username, is_ready: input.is_ready))
        return element.save(on: req.db)
            .map{ Party.Output(code: "200") }
        }
    }
```

When I try the code above I get the error `Fatal error: Children relation not eager loaded, use $ prefix to access: Children<Party, User>(for: [party_id]): file FluentKit/Children.swift, line 33` from the line

```
element.users.append(User(id: UUID(input.id), username: input.username, is_ready: input.is_ready))
```

When I comment this line the code runs and I get a return code.

I tried adding the prefix to `element.$users` and `$User` but then it complains about not being able to find `element.$users` and `$User` in scope.

`Party model`

```
import Fluent
import Vapor

final class Party: Model, Content {
    static let schema = "parties"

    struct JoinParty: Content {
        let id: String
        let username: String
        let is_ready: Bool
    }

    struct Output: Content {
        let code: String
    }
    
    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?

    @Field(key: "party_code")
    var party_code: String
    
    @Field(key: "host_id")
    var host_id: UUID

    @Field(key: "is_active")
    var is_active: Bool

    // change to Game when model is made
    @Field(key: "selected_games")
    var selected_games: [String]?

    // change to Setting when model is made  
    @Field(key: "settings")
    var settings: String

    @Field(key: "results")
    var results: Array<GameResult>?

    @Children(for: \.$party)
    var users: [User]

    init() { }

    init(id: UUID? = nil,
        party_code: String,
        host_id: UUID,
        is_active: Bool,
        selected_games: [String]? = nil,
        settings: String,
        results: Array<GameResult>? = nil) {
        self.id = id
        self.party_code = party_code
        self.host_id = host_id
        self.is_active = is_active
        self.selected_games = selected_games
        self.settings = settings
        self.results = results
    }
}
```

`User model`

```
import Fluent
import Vapor

final class User: Model, Content {
    static let schema = "users"

    struct Input: Content {
        let id: UUID
        let username: String
    }

    struct Output: Content {
        let id: String
        let username: String
    }
    
    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?

    @Field(key: "username")
    var username: String

    @Field(key: "is_ready")
    var is_ready: Bool

    @OptionalParent(key: "party_id")
    var party: Party?

    @Children(for: \.$user)
    var gameResults: [GameResult]

    init() {}

    init(id: UUID? = nil, username: String, is_ready: Bool, partyID: UUID? = nil) {
        self.id = id
        self.username = username
        self.is_ready = is_ready
        self.$party.id = partyID
    }
}
```

I have a similar function to update a username from a user already working which is almost the same thing.

```
func update(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<User.Output> {
      let input = try req.content.decode(User.Input.self)
        return User.find(input.id, on: req.db)
            .unwrap(or: Abort(.notFound))
            .flatMap { user in
                user.username = input.username
                return user.save(on: req.db)
                    .map { User.Output(id: user.id!.uuidString, username: user.username) }
            }
      }
```

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: it is easy to execute raw SQL with Fluent https://docs.vapor.codes/4.0/fluent/advanced/ if you will need typesafety instead of raw SQL strings you may take a look at SwifQL library for Vapor https://github.com/SwifQL/SwifQL and if one day you will choose SwifQL just join http://swift.stream community to ask any questions

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, adding children to a parent model is not that intuitive yet. I hope that someday we can get that added, but it's not there yet. Fluent 5 maybe?

Anyway, what you'll need to do instead is create your new `User` model, passing in the party's ID value to the `partyID` initializer parameter, and then save the `User` model.

```
let user = User(id: UUID(input.id), username: input.username, is_ready: input.is_ready, partyID: element.id)
return user.save(on: request.db)
```

So your method should end up looking like this:

```
func addToParty(req: Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<Party.Output> {
    guard let id = req.parameters.get("partyID", as: UUID.self) else {
        throw Abort(.badRequest)
    }
    let input = try req.content.decode(Party.JoinParty.self)

    return Party.find(id, on: req.db).unwrap(or: Abort(.notFound)).flatMap { element in
        return User(
            id: UUID(input.id), 
            username: input.username, 
            is_ready: input.is_ready,
            partyID: element.id
        ).save(on: req.db)
    }.transform(to: Party.Output(code: "200"))
}
```